# Updating field values if condition met, but leave the original values if condition not met in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, distance, expression, point-in-polygon

I'm sure this is probably quite simple but I'm still learning the syntax for field calc expressions. I have a points layer with the field `"Distance"` that I want to update using my expression:

```
if(
    distance(
        $geometry,
        geometry(
            get_feature('Site Boundary', 'id', '1')
            )
        ) = 0,
    '0',
    '1'
    )
```

In simple words: If(distance between current point feature and 'Site Boundary' polygon = 0, then write '0', else write '1'.

If a point is within the polygon 'Site Boundary', the distance function returns '0'. What is great, but my expression then overwrites all other values with '1'. How can I alter the expression to leave the original distance values if the condition is not met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the if-condition, change the `result_when_false` argument from `1` to the name of the field you are changing (`"your_fieldname"` in the following example): then the value of this field will be copied:

```
if(
    distance(
        $geometry,
        geometry(
            get_feature('Site Boundary', 'id', '1')
            )
        ) = 0,
    '0',
    "your_fieldname"
    )
```

---

By the way: setting zero in single quotes `'0'` results in an output formatted as a string (text). If you want a number (integer), simply write it without quotes: `0`. Or use a `case when ... then ... end` statment without `else`-part if you want to get no output in all other cases ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#case)).

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed! Unfortunately I've now reached a new limit in that I can't feed temporary layers from my model into the field calculator, and apparently this is currently not possible! Will have to get more creative...